# customizing PopUpMenuButton Control in flex

Tags: java, flash, apache-flex

I have a question regarding PopUpMenuButton Control.

The existing behavior of this control is :

“PopUpMenuButton Control has two buttons (main button and secondary button( looks like “v” down arraow symbol )) . When the user clicks the main button, the control dispatches an itemClick (MenuEvent.ITEM_CLICK) event that contains information about the selected menu item. Therefore, the same itemClick event is dispatched when the user clicks the main button or selects the current item from the pop-up menu. Because the same event is dispatched in both cases, clicking on the main button produces the same behavior as clicking on the last selected menuItem, so the main button plays the role of a frequently used menu item.”

In my application I got a requirement to change the existing functionality of the main button. It should not navigate to the frequently used menu item screen instead it should open the popup and it should behave exactly same as the secondary button ( v).

I tried with  openAlways=true property of PopUpMenuButton control. But it did not solve the problem completely. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT -

I already tried the option mentioned by TRISH below. But it is not solving my problem.

Whenever we click on the main button of PopUpMenuButton control two events will be dispatched. First click event will be dispatched followed by itemClick event. In the Click event handler we are writing code to open the popup so it is opening the popup and in the itemclick event handler respective page navigation code is there so it is navigating to that particular page. (These two are happening one by one so first popup is opening and within seconds it is navigating to the recently opened page because of itemclick handler code. So whenever we are clicking on main button these two actions are happening parallel hence we are getting a popup blink but not stable popup. If we modify anything in itemclick handler it is effecting the functionality of popup button because same handler for both the button clicks. Even the event target is also same in case of itemclick event irrespective of main button or popup button.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: It looks to me like the behavior of the PopUpButton might work better for you than the PopUpMenuButton. I wrote an application that illustrates the behavior that I'm understanding you would like:

- clicking on the main button opens the popup menu just like the arrow button
- clicking on the main button should not trigger the item click of the last selected menu item

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

      <fx:Script>
          <![CDATA[
              import mx.controls.Alert;
              import mx.controls.Menu;
              import mx.events.MenuEvent;

              [Bindable]
              private var menu:Menu;

              private function initMenu():void {
                  menu = new Menu();
                  var dp:Object = [
                          {label: "New Folder"}, 
                          {label: "Sent Items"}, 
                          {label: "Inbox"}
                      ];        
                  menu.dataProvider = dp;
                  menu.addEventListener("itemClick", changeHandler);
              }

              private function changeHandler(event:MenuEvent):void {
                  var label:String = event.label;        
                  Alert.show(label);
                  // popUpButton.label = event.label;
                  popUpButton.close();
              }           
          ]]>
      </fx:Script>

      <s:VGroup>
          <mx:PopUpButton id="popUpButton" openAlways="true"
                                          label="Select a control..." 
                                          popUp="{menu}"
                                          preinitialize="initMenu()" />   
      </s:VGroup>
  </s:Application>
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Trish... I tried the same approach previously but dint find any luck... Can you please refer my updated question again and let me know your thoughts please..

Comment: Thank you so much Trish, it worked +1 for your answer and also accepted your answer :-)